# No such interface supported

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function in angular stored as a variable which is as follows:

```
job.addAddress = function() {
    // Setup the object to pass to API
    var addressObj = {};
    $(".form__input__address").each(function () {
        var name = this.name;
        var value = this.value;
        addressObj[name] = value;
    });
    console.log(addressObj);
}
```

And the HTML / Angular that calls the function is:

```
<button id="addAddressBtn" ng-click="job.addAddress()" class="btn btn-default">Add Address to Book</button>
```

The button is in scope as is seen here in html:

```
<!-- Add Job Main -->
<main class="main" ng-controller="JobController as job">
    <div class="wrap">
        <h4>New Job</h4>
        <a ng-click="job.back()" class="backlink"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-left"></i> Go Back</a>

        <img id="ajaxLoader" src="../Content/images/ajaxLoad.gif" height="64" />
        <pre id="ajaxResult">&nbsp;</pre>

        <form id="form" class="form js-form" data-formtype="Add Job"></form>
        <button id="addJob" ng-click="job.addJob()" class="btn btn-default">Add Job</button>
    </div>

    <div id="AddressBook" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Address Book</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div id="AddressHeading">
                        <h4>Please select an address from the address book...</h4>    
                    </div>
                    <div id="addAddressReveal">
                        <button id="addAddressToggle" ng-click="job.addAddressReveal($event)" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                    </div>

                    <table id="addresses"></table>

                    <h4 id="addAddressTitle">Add an Address</h4>
                    <div id="addAddress" class="form__section__group">
                        <label class="form__label ">
                            Company
                            <span class="tooltip">
                                <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
                                <span class="tooltip__content">Enter the company name</span>
                            </span>
                            <input name="CompanyName" class="form__input__address js-required" type="text">
                        </label>
                        <label class="form__label ">
                            Building Name / No.
                            <span class="tooltip">
                                <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
                                <span class="tooltip__content">Enter the building name or number</span>
                            </span>
                            <input name="BuildingNameOrNo" class="form__input__address js-required" type="text"  placeholder="e.g. '123' or 'Solutions House'">
                        </label>
                        <label class="form__label ">
                            Street Name
                            <span class="tooltip">
                                <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
                                <span class="tooltip__content">Enter the name of the street</span>
                            </span>
                            <input name="StreetName" class="form__input__address js-required" type="text" >
                        </label>
                        <label class="form__label ">
                            Locality
                            <span class="tooltip">
                                <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
                                <span class="tooltip__content">Enter the name of the local area</span>
                            </span>
                            <input name="Locality" class="form__input__address js-required" type="text" placeholder="e.g. 'Croydon'">
                        </label>
                        <label class="form__label ">
                            City
                            <span class="tooltip">
                                <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
                                <span class="tooltip__content">Enter the name of the city</span>
                            </span>
                            <input name="City" class="form__input__address js-required" type="text" placeholder="e.g. 'London'">
                        </label>
                        <label class="form__label ">
                            County
                            <span class="tooltip">
                                <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
                                <span class="tooltip__content">Enter the county</span>
                            </span>
                            <input name="Postcode" class="form__input__address js-required" type="text" placeholder="e.g. 'Staffordshire'">
                        </label>
                        <label class="form__label ">
                            Post code
                            <span class="tooltip">
                                <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
                                <span class="tooltip__content">Enter the postal code</span>
                            </span>
                            <input name="Postcode" class="form__input__address js-required" type="text" placeholder="e.g. 'ST5 9QF'">
                        </label>
                        <label class="form__label ">
                            Contact Name
                            <span class="tooltip">
                                <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
                                <span class="tooltip__content">Enter the name of a contact at this address</span>
                            </span>
                            <input name="ContactName" class="form__input__address js-required" type="text">
                        </label>
                        <label class="form__label ">
                            Contact Phone Number
                            <span class="tooltip">
                                <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
                                <span class="tooltip__content">Enter the phone number of a contact at this address</span>
                            </span>
                            <input name="ContactNumber" class="form__input__address js-required" type="text">
                        </label>
                        <label class="form__label ">
                            Tail Lift?
                            <span class="tooltip">
                                <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
                                <span class="tooltip__content">Is a taillift required for this address?</span>
                            </span>
                            <div class="form__label--radio">
                                <input name="Tailift" id="TailiftYes" type="radio" value="Yes">
                                <label for="TailiftYes">
                                    <i class="fa fa-check-circle active"></i><i class="fa fa-circle-thin inactive"></i>Yes
                                </label>
                                <input name="Tailift" id="TailiftNo" type="radio" checked="checked" value="No">
                                <label for="TailiftNo">
                                    <i class="fa fa-check-circle active"></i><i class="fa fa-circle-thin inactive"></i>No
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </label>
                        <label class="form__label ">
                            Rigid Vehicle?
                            <span class="tooltip">
                                <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
                                <span class="tooltip__content">Is a rigid vehicle required for this delivery?</span>
                            </span>
                            <div class="form__label--radio">
                                <input name="Rigid" id="RigidYes" type="radio" value="Yes">
                                <label for="RigidYes">
                                    <i class="fa fa-check-circle active"></i><i class="fa fa-circle-thin inactive"></i>Yes
                                </label>
                                <input name="Rigid" id="RigidNo" type="radio" checked="checked" value="No">
                                <label for="RigidNo"><i class="fa fa-check-circle active"></i><i class="fa fa-circle-thin inactive"></i>No</label>
                            </div>
                        </label>
                        <label class="form__label js-booking">
                            Booking Required?<span class="tooltip">
                                <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
                                <span class="tooltip__content">Is a booking required for this delivery?</span>
                            </span>
                            <div class="form__label--radio">
                                <input name="RingForBooking" id="RingForBookYes" type="radio" value="Yes">
                                <label for="RingForBookYes">
                                    <i class="fa fa-check-circle active"></i><i class="fa fa-circle-thin inactive"></i>Yes
                                </label>
                                <input name="RingForBooking" id="RingForBookNo" type="radio" checked="checked" value="No">
                                <label for="RingForBookNo">
                                    <i class="fa fa-check-circle active"></i><i class="fa fa-circle-thin inactive"></i>No
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </label>
                        <label class="form__label form__label--fullwidth">
                            Notes
                            <span class="tooltip">
                                <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i><span class="tooltip__content">Is there anything else you need to know?</span>
                            </span>


               <textarea name="Notes" class="form__input form__input--textarea" placeholder="Anything else we need to know?" type="text"></textarea>
                    </label>
                    <button id="addAddressBtn" ng-click="job.addAddress()" class="btn btn-default">Add Address to Book</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

I have a very similar function (only change is different names for the object variable), which works with no issues, however when the page loads I'm getting the error:

> SCRIPT16386: No such interface supported

The error is pointing to line 123 which is:

```
group.appendChild(job.addAddress(line["Name"].toString(), line["HelpText"].toString(), line["FieldName"].toString(), line["TextType"].toString(), line["Placeholder"].toString(), "NO", line["ExtraClass"].toString()));
```

The rest of the function for this line is:

```
// Load all elements to the page from Job Def API
job.addElements = function (data) {
    var form = document.getElementById("form");
    var sName = "";
    var gName = "";
    var section;
    var group;
    jQuery.each(data.Data, function (no, line) {
        if (line["Section"].toString() != sName) {
            if (typeof section === "object") {
                section.appendChild(group);
                form.appendChild(section);
            }
            section = job.addSection(line["Section"].toString());
            var h = document.createElement("H2");
            var t = document.createTextNode(line["SectionName"].toString());
            h.appendChild(t);
            section.appendChild(h);
            sName = line["Section"].toString();
            group = job.addSectionGroup(sName + line["SectionGroup"].toString());
            gName = line["SectionGroup"].toString();
        }
        if (line["SectionGroup"].toString() != gName) {
            if (typeof group === "object") {
                section.appendChild(group);
                group = job.addSectionGroup(sName + line["SectionGroup"].toString());
                gName = line["SectionGroup"].toString();
            }
        }
        switch (line["Type"].toString()) {
            case "TXT":
                group.appendChild(job.addTextBox(line["Name"].toString(), line["HelpText"].toString(), line["FieldName"].toString(), line["TextType"].toString(), line["Placeholder"].toString(), "NO", line["ExtraClass"].toString()));
            break;
            case "TDW":
                group.appendChild(job.addTextBox(line["Name"].toString(), line["HelpText"].toString(), line["FieldName"].toString(), line["TextType"].toString(), line["Placeholder"].toString(), "DW", line["ExtraClass"].toString()));
            break;
            case "TFW":
                group.appendChild(job.addTextBox(line["Name"].toString(), line["HelpText"].toString(), line["FieldName"].toString(), line["TextType"].toString(), line["Placeholder"].toString(), "FW", line["ExtraClass"].toString()));
            break;
            case "LST":
                group.appendChild(job.addSelect(line["Name"].toString(), line["HelpText"].toString(), line["FieldName"].toString(), line["Items"].toString().split("^"), line["Selected"], "NO", line["ExtraClass"].toString()));
            break;
            case "DPK":
                group.appendChild(job.addDatePicker(line["Name"].toString(), line["HelpText"].toString(), line["FieldName"].toString(), line["TextType"].toString(), line["Placeholder"].toString()));
            break;
            case "TAR":
                group.appendChild(job.addTextArea(line["Name"].toString(), line["HelpText"].toString(), line["FieldName"].toString(), line["TextType"].toString(), line["Placeholder"].toString()));
            break;
            case "ADR":
                group.appendChild(job.addAddress(line["Name"].toString(), line["HelpText"].toString(), line["FieldName"].toString(), line["TextType"].toString(), line["Placeholder"].toString(), "NO", line["ExtraClass"].toString()));
            break;
            case "NST":
             group.appendChild(job.addNumberStepper(line["Name"].toString(), line["HelpText"].toString(), line["FieldName"].toString(), line["TextType"].toString(), "0"));
            break; //face
            case "RAD":
                group.appendChild(job.addOptions(line["Name"].toString(), line["HelpText"].toString(), line["FieldName"].toString(), line["Items"].toString().split("^"), line["Selected"], "NO", line["ExtraClass"].toString()));
            break;
            case "RDW":
                group.appendChild(job.addOptions(line["Name"].toString(), line["HelpText"].toString(), line["FieldName"].toString(), line["Items"].toString().split("^"), line["Selected"], "DW", line["ExtraClass"].toString()));
                break;
            }
        });
        if (typeof section === "object") {
            section.appendChild(group);
            form.appendChild(section);
        }

    }
```

Which is completely unrelated to the code that breaks the application from above. When I remove the addAddress function, the code runs with no issues, but as soon as this is added back in the code breaks with the same error. What on earth is going on?

Comment: You need to show more complete code. The first questions that comes to mind are, "is the `job` object added to your scope?" and "is the controller (or directive) in scope for the `button` element?" Without more complete code it could be any of a million things.

Comment: I don't see any function arguments in job.addAddress = function() { ... } so your call in line 123 is invalid because there is no such function which accepts your arguments.

Comment: Yes to both of those questions - I've added the HTML to show the scope of the HTML

Comment: @getjackx - thanks - didn't notice they were named the same :)

Comment: I still don't see where the `job` object is defined. Your declaration, `job.addAddress = function() {...`, assumes `job` is already defined. Where? We need to see more of the controller definition.

Comment: It was just defined in the app like it should have been, the problem was that the address function has the same name of an existing one

Comment: Have you verified it's working? AFAIK that should not be an error in javascript. The args should just be ignored.

Comment: I have yeah - it works as expected when I changed the name